# How to get timestamp from date in elastic search script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

As the title suggests, I want to get the timestamp (as a number) from a date type in an elastic search painless script. The following attempts didn't work: `doc["date_field"].value`, `doc["date_field"].date.getMillis()`.

Comment: Are you trying to get only the time value from a date type field ? For ex. get 00:10:10 from date field value 18th October, 2018 00:10:10 ?

Comment: @ben5556 I want to get a timestamp, like milliseconds since unix epoch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Painless docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html#modules-scripting-painless-dates) you should be able to access the milliseconds since epoch like this: `doc.date_field.millis`.

> Date fields are exposed as `ReadableDateTime`, so they support methods
>   like `getYear`, `getDayOfWeek` or e.g. getting milliseconds since epoch
>   with `getMillis`. To use these in a script, leave out the get prefix and
>   continue with lowercasing the rest of the method name.

You should also be able to use the methods from `ReadableDateTime`. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.4/painless-api-reference.html#painless-api-reference-org-joda-time-ReadableDateTime

Comment: I have retested with `doc["date_field"].date.millis` and it worked! it seems that I had a bug on previous attempt